# What are the legal issues when using free Unity Assets on a commercial game?

Tags: unity, assets

In the unity asset store one can find tons of thousands of assets, a lot of them being distributed for free.

When using a free Unity Asset is it implied that you can do anything with it(commercial or not)?

Is there any legal agreement concerning free Unity Assets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a quick Google would have given you the answer

There are a couple relevant points in the [FAQ](https://unity3d.com/unity/faq) pertaining to licence and use of assets from example projects etc.

Unity stack answer :
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/342714/use-of-asset-store-assests-in-commercial-game.html

> "You can use any asset from the store personally and commercially, you
>   can edit this object by changing materials, editing the Geometry etc
>
> You can NOT re-distribute the file, no matter how much you modify it
>   you can use it but not share or re-sell it.
>
> Most of those conditions are there to prevent illegal activity or
>   cover the author/unity team in the case of lawsuits. As a genuine
>   paying user there is no need to worry about any of it, in the event
>   that you accidentally breach a condition (such as redistribute a
>   bought material on one of your models) unity will likely contact you
>   and ask you to remove that component rather than outright sue."

Comment: Please also put the information which can be found at the link you posted to your answer. Otherwise your answer will be useless when that link ever becomes invalid.